# How to redirect output of more to a file

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, more

I would like to pipe the output of `tree` command to `more`, ignoring the first line. Then redirect the output of `more` command to a file. If I type

```
tree SOME_DIRECTORY | more +2 >> OUTPUT_FILE
```

The first line still appears in OUTPUT_FILE.

But if I type

```
tree SOME_DIRECTORY | more +2
```

the first line doesn't appear on the terminal.

Can anyone point out what mistake I was making ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

more (or less) are rather to be used interactively.

use either `tail`

```
tree SOME_DIRECTORY | tail +2 >> output_file
```

this tell tail to list line, starting from 2nd (line N°2)

or `awk`

```
tree SOME_DIRECTORY | awk 'NR>1' >> output_file
```

this tell awk to print (default action) line whose number (NR: Number Record) is above 1 (you can also use `NR>=2` )

or sed (thank to  Kusalananda )

```
tree SOME_DIRECTORY | sed -n '2,$p' >> output_file
```

where

- `-n` do not print input
- `2,$` select line  from 2 to end of file
- `p` print

Comment: Or `sed -n '2,$p'`

Comment: Or `( read && cat ) <file >newfile`  ;-)